# How to make Gnus auto-expire RSS

Tags: gnus

I'm very new to Gnus. I have added some feeds by using G R. As far as I understand, the feed is modified by the server (by adding new "messages" and removing old "messages") and when Gnus loads it every time, the new messages are downloaded and the old messages which disappeared from the server feed are not deleted in Gnus. I don't want to keep forever the feeds which I read, therefore I activated auto-expire on the groups corresponding to my feeds. However, every time I read one of the messages in one of my feeds, it doesn't get marked with E (in fact, it will show up as Old, eventually). When I exit the group with q, I read something similar to "setting as expiring"  but when I go back in nothing has changed. In fact, I tried to "purge all messages which are set as expiring" and none was deleted. Does auto-expire only work for emails, and did I understand correctly how Gnus's retrieve pipline works for RSS?